# What are the minimal Gradle settings needed to support converting Kotlin files in an Android Studio App into Javascript using kotlin2js?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-android-extensions

Currently, I have two build.gradles. One for the app, and one for the project.

For the App build.gradle, I have:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "someId"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/someSDK.jar')
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

For the Project build.gradle, I have:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += "${projectDir}/src/main/java/pathToFilesConvertedFromJavaToKotlin"

}

compileKotlin2Js {
    kotlinOptions.metaInfo = true
    kotlinOptions.outputFile = "$project.buildDir.path/js/${project.name}.js"
    kotlinOptions.sourceMap = true
    kotlinOptions.moduleKind = 'commonjs'
    kotlinOptions.main = "call"
}

ext {
    minSdkVersion = 15
    targetSdkVersion = 23
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = '23.0.3'

    xmlunitVersion = '1.6'
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    mockitoVersion = '1.10.19'
    hamcrestVersion = '1.3'
}
```

When I compile and run, the app works and no errors occur. However, I do not see my javascript file that should have been produced from those Kotlin files.

Any ideas as to why?

Please note, I have tried using: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/getting-started-gradle/getting-started-with-gradle.html as a guide. The issue with this example is that it suggests using the taskAssemble below. However, this contains File, which is not recognized as a keyword in my build.gradle for some reason.

```
task assembleWeb(type: Sync) {
    configurations.compile.each { File file ->
        from(zipTree(file.absolutePath), {
            includeEmptyDirs = false
            include { fileTreeElement ->
                def path = fileTreeElement.path
                path.endsWith(".js") && (path.startsWith("META-INF/resources/") || 
                    !path.startsWith("META-INF/"))
            }
        })
    }
    from compileKotlin2Js.destinationDir
    into "${projectDir}/web"

    dependsOn classes
}

assemble.dependsOn assembleWeb
```

Comment: Check [this](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/kotlin-to-javascript/kotlin-to-javascript.html) and [this](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/getting-started-gradle/getting-started-with-gradle.html)

Comment: @itsmysterybox, I already looked at those. When using that task assembleWeb, the keyword File isn't recognized.

Comment: @itsmysterybox, I updated my response to indicate the issues that I experienced with those guides.

Comment: Try to use File keyword and sync project. Shows any error?

Comment: @itsmysterybox Yep. I even cleaned my project. I also tried invalidating the cache. Did not work.

Comment: See this [post](https://medium.com/@czuckie/experimenting-with-kotlin2js-and-qunit-gradle-ab2164af695)

Comment: @itsmysterybox, that example uses the File class. I'm also using Android Studio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181003/discussion-between-floam-and-itsmysterybox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now, I believe the issue is that you cannot compile Java Byte Code into Javascript via kotlin2js. Since I have Android references in my code, and those references are compiled into Java Byte Code, my Kotlin scripts cannot successfully be converted into Javascript. However, I have come across an interesting article that could be of use to anyone looking to build Kotlin based applications that can work across multiple platforms: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html